# Selenium FirefoxDriver page load timeout

Tags: java, sockets, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

Some pages are loading really slow and therefore I need to specify some page load timeout.. for example 60 seconds after which the load process will be interrupted.

How I can specify page load timeout in my Java application for Selenium FirefoxDriver ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Explicit and Implicit Waits which are supported by Selenium, you can see in http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Or you can wait for some objects in the page you might want to get as below (I wrote in Python but I think you can understand idea)

```
while ('Loading' in driver.page_source) and t < 5:
  driver.implicitly_wait(t * time_waiting / 3)
  t =+ 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but AFAIK it will not only affect timeout for `driver.get` method but it will also affect all other waits for example `driver.findElement`.. But I need only to change a timeout for `driver.get` method

Comment: you can try this, 
while ('Something' in driver.page_source) and t < 5:
        driver.implicitly_wait(time_waiting)
        t ++